# Ajaxful-Rating Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why am I getting this error ?

```
/Users/judyngai/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/ajaxful_rating-2.2.9.1/lib/axr/model.rb:23: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
```

I made a new app in rails 4 and ruby 2.0 - the latest versions
I installed the ajaxful-rating gem into my rails app and ran bundle install (version 2.2.9.1)

I changed my database yml file to use pg then do

rake db:create

and this error popped up. Is the gem not compatible with rails 4? I consider this issue before hand maybe I should switch to rails 3.2 ?

Comment: Seems like some sort of issue with parsing hashes. You might want to open a ticket (https://github.com/edgarjs/ajaxful-rating/issues)

Comment: the gem was updated a year ago, there were no ruby-2.0 and rails 4.0 back then. I think this gem is not for you.